# How to access style of scalar used in a YAML value in ruamel?

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, ruamel.yaml

Take this example code:

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
import sys

yaml = YAML(pure=True)
yaml.allow_duplicate_keys = True
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
internal_dictionary = yaml.load("Key: \"value\"")
yaml.dump(code, sys.stdout)
```

Output:

```
Key: "value"
```

The internal_dictionary contains:

Key: value

But in the dump and the input file the value is between two ", ruamel knows this as it gets dumped correctly, is there I way where I can see it too in the phase where it is stored in the internal_dictionary without the two "?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you load with `yaml.preserve_quotes = True`, if your scalar is unquoted and has no anchor (and is not recognised as a float, datetime, boolean, etc), the type of `internal_dictionary['Key']` will be a normal Python string.

If the scalar is not an unquoted string , one of the types from [`ruamel/yaml/scalarstring.py`](https://sourceforge.net/p/ruamel-yaml/code/ci/default/tree/scalarstring.py) is created: `SingleQuotedScalarString`, `DoubleQuotedScalarString`, `LiteralScalaString`, `FoldedScalarString`, `PlainScalarString`. These are all subclasses of `ScalarString` that handles the attachment of anchor for round-trip preservation.

SclarString is a subclass of `str`, which makes your output contain `value` if you inspect `internal_dictionary`.

So what you can do is e.g. test using `isinstance(internal_dictionary['Key'], ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.DoubleQuotedScalarstring)`, or you can test on the 'style' attribute:

```
if internal_dictionary['Key'].style == '"':
```

Comment: Is it possible to access this information from the list of variables in the python debugger?

Comment: I assume it is, as these are normal python instances. But I have never tried myself.

Comment: Do you have any clue where that might be, [see debug output](https://i.ibb.co/ZcrDW8t/code.png)?

Comment: As stated in my answer, you have to look at the value ( `internal_dictionary['key']`),  in your screenshot you are inspecting the dict (`internal_dictionary`)

Answer (score 0):

An exact answer would probably require a look at the code, but we see that the values have different data types.

The default type would be a string, but when the value is quoted, the type is a `ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.DoubleQuotedScalarString` with the "style" property.

[image: rich inspect ruamel.yaml]

Comment: Is it possible to access this information from the list of variables in the python debugger?

Comment: Yes, it is. They are normal Python objects, so you can definitely access this information in the debugger

Comment: Do you have any clue where that might be, [see debug output](https://i.ibb.co/ZcrDW8t/code.png)?

Comment: I am not familiar with the VScode debugger but you should be able to do a `type(internal_dictionary["Key"])` in the Watch section